# How to determine which desktop environment is installed from the shell?

Tags: command-line, kali-linux, ps, desktop-environment

The only Desktop Environment I ever used was Xfce, now for sheer curiosity, I installed Kali Linux. I clicked here and there on the Desktop in a vain hope to get info about the Environment itself. Is there a standard procedure to check the name of the Desktop Environment from the command-line, maybe something like:

```
ps -e | grep xxx
```

but then, I do not know what I could try to grep.

I just mentioned Kali Linux as an example, I would like to know how to do it in general.

Comment: Which desktop environment is **running**, or which desktop environments **are** installed?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To check the name of the Desktop Environment from the command line, you can use the following command:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

or

```
ls /usr/share/xsessions/
```

Or based on the question:

```
ps -e | grep -E -i "xfce|kde|gnome"
```

Sample output (kde):

```
 kdevtmpfs
 start_kdeinit
 kdeinit4
 kded4
 polkit-kde-auth
```