# How can I boot into KDE on Debian?

Tags: debian, kde, sddm

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)
Release: 9.8
Codename: stretch

$ /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/bin/sddm
```

I am attempting to display the KDE Plasma desktop environment, and be able to interact with it normally.

I installed KDE with the [commands here](https://www.rootusers.com/install-kde-gui-debian-9-linux/):

```
$ apt install aptitude tasksel
$ aptitude install ~t^desktop$ ~t^kde-desktop$
```

If I start my computer and boot into Debian, it shows the login screen, and my user name is selected, however it does not accept a password. It is not interactive and won't even give an error if the password is incorrect. Also, in the top left corner, under `Session`, there is nothing in the dropdown menu at all.

Originally, TWM was intalled, but I deleted that with `apt-get` and then immediately installed SDDM. I'm thinking during this process I didn't fully install or configure SDDM?

Comment: When you are on the login screen is it your old display manager or the new one? Is it possible for you to change over to a different tty?

Comment: @kemotep It is the new one! And yes it's possible to change to a different tty. The command line is fully interactive, I just can't boot into the GUI.

Comment: What version of kde do you have installed? I am seeing bug reports related to this issue but from 2016, however they are for Arch so perhaps Debian is on that very same version. Your installation methods seem out of place, to install kde I simply ran `apt install kde` rebooted and everything worked just fine.

Comment: @kemotep i'm not sure exactly. If I follow this link none of the commands show anything in my terminal: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366052/how-to-determine-which-desktop-environment-is-installed-from-the-shell

Comment: You can see what version of kde you have installed using `apt-cache policy kde` or some variation of that. If you are in a tty that is not running a graphical instance then you will not see any results following those steps...

Comment: @kemotep `apt-cache policy kde` yields: `Installed: (none), Candidate: (none), Version table: `. Which I don't understand because I installed it with the steps in my question, but perhaps those did not completely install?

Comment: Try looking for `kde-plasma-desktop` if you do not have it installed try installing it via apt.

Comment: `apt-cache policy kde-plasma-desktop`, returns: `Installed: (none), Candidate: 5:92, Version table: 5:92 500 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages`. Thank you for the help so far